# JSP can't find stylesheets, images

Tags: java, jsp, tags, jstl, stylesheet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JSP can't find stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626689/jsp-cant-find-stylesheet)

Tomcat7, spring framework3, jstl 1.2.
Hierarchy: WEB-INF/jsp WEB-INF/styles

I link stylesheet in my JSP file, which is located in WEB-INF/jsp: But it doesn't work! When i open my application there is no styles, and writter by Tomcat:

```
Apache Tomcat/7.0.14 - Error report
HTTP Status 404 -

type Status report

message

description The requested resource () is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.14
```

So i put my styles folder out of WEB-INF and it still doesn't work!
Also, images too don't work, but my images folder not in WEB-INF and their path is corect...
What is the problem?

Comment: You already asked the same exact questions, and got a response: you can't put the CSS files in WEB-INF. If you want more help, edit your original question, show us the code of your JSP, and tell us where all the related files are in the tree of directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Spring I put my resources in a folder outside of web-inf.  Like this:

[image]

Web.xml

```
<!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

Then in my servlet-context.xml (configuration file specified in web.xml) file I exclude the resources directory from being managed by the dispatcher, so URLs prefixed with resources/ are not picked up by the dispatcher and attempted to be routed to an appropriate controller.

```
<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

In my jsp I can then access resources as normal:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/skillsmanager-ui/resources/css/reset.css" />
```

Comment: @Lomer glad you got it working thanks for accepting. I had problems with this too when I first set it up.  Just remember that your dispatcher is going to pick up all your requests and try to route them unless you have a rule setup to prevent it